# How to include BigQuery Connector inside Dataproc using Livy

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, livy

I'm trying to run my application using Livy that resides inside GCP Dataproc but I'm getting this: "*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigquery.DefaultSource*"

I'm able to run **hadoop fs -ls gs://xxxx** inside Dataproc and I checked if Spark is pointing to the right location in order to find gcs-connector.jar and that's ok too.

I included Livy in Dataproc using initialization (https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/master/livy/)

How can I include bigquery-connector in Livy's classpath?
Could you help me, please?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your application is depending on the BigQuery connector, not the GCS connector (`bigquery.DefaultSource`).

The GCS connector should always be included in the HADOOP classpath by default, but you will have to manually add the BigQuery connector jar to your application.

Assuming this is a Spark application, you can set the Spark jar property to pull in the bigquery connector jar from GCS at runtime: `spark.jars='gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar'`

For more installation options, see https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/README.md